# How to fix a "System.ArgumentException: 'Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: name'" in a MVC app?

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller, view, model

I've been working on a summer project where we have to create a portfolio web app where someone can look through a number of potential candidates and select the best one. I've created a SQL database and within there is information and how confident they are in a programming language with a number from 0 - 5. I've created the MVC app and tried to create a new candidate but I am getting this error and have no previous experience coding in this language so am unsure on what to do. Here is my code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Candidate</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.First_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.First_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.First_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Last_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Last_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Last_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date_of_birth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date_of_birth, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date_of_birth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C__NET___ASP, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.C__NET___ASP, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.C__NET___ASP, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CSS, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CSS, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CSS, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HTML, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HTML, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HTML, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Java, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Java, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Java, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JavaScript, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JavaScript, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JavaScript, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Python, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Python, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Python, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Python_Flask, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Python_Flask, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Python_Flask, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Any help to fix this issue or come at this project in another way would be amazing!

Comment: This code seems to be missing the model declaration at the top of page. Also how do you pass the model from the controller code that opens this view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caused by `__` (double underscores) in the variable name `C__NET___ASP`.
You can use `C_NET_ASP` or `CNetAsp` instead to solve the issue.

I found similar error reported for ASP.NET Core: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18913